# Apparent memory leak while using 2D vector in C++

Tags: c++, gdb

I decided to use C++ 2D vectors for an applications. While testing some code I encountered a `bad alloc` error. I read that this may be caused by memory shortage so I investigated my program's memory use by calling the `malloc_stats` function at different steps in gdb.
While I am not sure I completely understand the output of the function, it seems to indicate memory leaks.

I tried to sum up the problem in the short code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<double>> get_predictions(){
    vector<vector<double>> predictions;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        vector<double> new_state;
        new_state.push_back(600);
        new_state.push_back(450);
        new_state.push_back(100);
        new_state.push_back(200);
        predictions.push_back(new_state);
    }
    return predictions;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "start" << endl;

    // time loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        auto predictions = get_predictions();
        // code that uses the latest predictions
    }

    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I call `malloc_stats()` at the "start" line, the output is similar to this:

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =      74352
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =      74352
max mmap regions =          0
max mmap bytes   =          0
```

At the "end" step, the function gives:

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =      75568
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =      75568
max mmap regions =          0
max mmap bytes   =          0
```

The "In use bytes" field clearly increased.

Does it really mean that more allocated memory is held ?

If so, why ? Shouldn't the allocated content be freed once the different vectors go out of scope ?

Then, how to avoid such memory issues ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No leaks in provided code.

Comment: Maybe memory fragmentation.

Comment: Does the amount of memory being 'used' increase when you increase the loop size, like changing `i < 10` to `i < 1000` (in the `get_predicitions` function, that is)? Could just be some lingering, left-over space allocated by the implementation of `std::vector`.

Comment: GDB seems fine to me. Have you tried Valgrind?

Comment: `get_predictions` can be simplified to `auto get_predictions() {
    return std::vector<std::vector<double>>(10, {600., 450., 100., 200.});}`

Comment: `malloc_stats` is badly documented. What to do with badly documented things? Well [this article](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/659137-malloc_stats-output) states that _in use bytes_ really means something else, what you'd expect it means. I agree with @ArunSuryan, better use valgrind.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429866/strange-behavior-in-malloc-stats-function

Comment: It is not possible to have any leak in this code, but I tried valgrind anyway. It confirmed that there is no leak.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank for the suggestion, but this is a simplified case and I normally fill the prediction vectors with different values. That said, I did not know this syntax :)

Comment: @nada, darcamo, Mutable, Arun thank for your responses, the related post seems to indeed indicate that I should not have used malloc_stats in first place ! I did not know valgrind and will try it as soon as possible to find out where my true memory leak lies. Thank you all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the suggestions in comments, I abandoned malloc_stats, which does not seem to behave as I expected, and tried out Valgrind on my code.

Valgrind confirms that there is no leak in the toy example above.

Concerning my main application, it is a program running on ARM. For reasons unknown to me, the base Valgrind implementation gotten *via* `apt install valgrind` did not output the lines concerned by memory leaks. I had to recompile it from sources available on Valgrind website. The problem must come from architecture-specific particularities ?

As a side-note, my application also uses CUDA code, which implies many false positives in Valgrind outputs.